# Events in Excel for the web

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am using script in Excel for the Web and it is working fine. Now I try to use events but it does not seem to work there, are the events in excel Excel web supported ? Something like this from the tutorial:

```
  const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
  sheet.onActivated.add(function (event) {
    return Excel.run(async (context) => {
      console.log("The activated worksheet ID is: " + event.worksheetId);
      await context.sync();
    });
  });
  await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: This should work in Excel on the web. Can you reproduce the problem in the Script Lab tool?

Comment: I did not. But in the meantime I discovered that it was not supported yet in Excel online. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [Excel API 1.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheet-onactivated-member) is supported by the host application. Read more about events in Excel in the [Work with Events using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) article.